# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH on Jhipster

Tags: spring, spring-boot, https, jhipster, tls1.2

I'm deploying my first application with Jhipster.
First, i launched the application with standard HTTP support on 8080 port, and everythings works correctly.
Now i want to upgrade to HTTPS, but so far, I haven't been able to get to the bottom of it.

I package the application as JAR, and deployed it on Ubuntu server 18.04 with jdk 1.8. I followed the documentation provided by Jhipster to generate a let's encrypt on this link (https://maximilian-boehm.com/hp2121/Create-a-Java-Keystore-JKS-from-Let-s-Encrypt-Certificates.htm); i tested the jks producted with https://ssllabs.com and i received an overall rating of A.

This is a part of my application-prod.yml :

```
server:
    port: 10443
    ssl:
        enabled: true
        key-store: keystore.jks
        key-store-password: mypassword
        keyStoreType: PKCS12
        key-alias: selfsigned
        ciphers: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2
```

When i launch the jar, the application starts normally,
but when i try to connect to homepage,

I got back "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH"

i tryed to change ciphers but it doesn't works.

Thank you

Comment: Hi think that is better for you to use a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the problem is that you are using a lower version Jhipster, but using the ssl properties from a higher version or vice versa.

- Check if the path provided in key-store property matches with the file path.
- Then check if the SSL properties that you are using matches the one similar to your version. I am using Jhipster version 3.0.7 and spring version 5.1.11.

```
ssl:  
    key-store: classpath:config/tls/keystore.p12
    key-store-password: ****
    key-store-type: pkcs12
    key-alias : yourAlias
    ciphers: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2
```

- Lastest version of Jhipster uses:

```
ssl:
    key-store: keystore.p12
    key-store-password: <your-password>
    keyStoreType: PKCS12
    keyAlias: <your-application>
    ciphers: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2
```

- Assuming your SSL configuration is correct, recheck the procedure that you have used for creating a key. If you have used OPENSSL for creating .key and .csr file Cerificate Authority and have got the .crt files from them. Then use following command for creating a PKCS file. **A thing to note here** is that alias is not asked while creating the file, so you shouldn't provide it in SSL config.

```
openssl pkcs12 --export -out keystore.p12 -inkey <key-name>.key -in <cert-name>.crt
```